# 2003 Mazda Tribute (Ford Escape) Front Clunk: Not the tie rods or ball joint

Tags: ford, suspension, mazda, steering

I've been frustrated by the clunk in the front of my car for the seven years since I bought it. Just recently it became incredibly loud when. Some details:

**Exclusively occurs when the Front Left tire goes over a bump of any kind.** I've done angled drives over curbs to determine left or right, it's left for sure.

**It's noticeable through the floorboards.** I had a friend visiting and he could feel it as well despite never having been in the car when it didn't have the clunk, so I'm not just hypersensitive.

**Both ball joints and tie rods have been replaced in the last four years.** I had a catastrophic failure on the right wheel of the ball joint, both were replaced. Tie rods were replaced as an early attempt to eliminate the clunk (failed). They are still in excellent condition, and the there is zero play in either of these parts.

**There is no play in the front wheels.** There are no steering issues, no change in feeling when at high speeds, no movement in the control arm when moved with leverage, and so on. Rocking the entire wheel while the car is off and brakes engage results in no sounds, no movement, no sense of anything being loose.

**None of the rubber components of bushings appear worn** (other than aging as it's an older vehicle), pushed out, or otherwise damaged.

I will be taking it to local mechanics next week to get professional advice, but I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this. Online people seem hooked on the tie rods or ball joint solution. That won't solve anything for me, as those parts have all been replaced fairly recently.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you checked the top of the Macpherson strut?

Comment: Could also be an  internal fault in a shock absorber (damper).